# Unable to set the custom header view in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to make the custom header for the UITableView but it is showing the "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". The code is like this:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
   let headerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: 40))
    self.headerImage?.frame = CGRect(x: (headerImage?.frame.size.width)! + 20, y: 20, width: 10, height: 10)
    headerLbl?.frame = CGRect(x: (headerImage?.frame.size.width)! + 20, y: 20, width: 10, height: 10)
    arrowImage?.isHidden = true
    arrowImage?.frame = CGRect(x: menuTableView.frame.size.width - 30, y: 20, width: 10, height: 10)
    if selectedIndex == section {
      arrowImage?.image = UIImage(named: "down arrow")
    } else {
      arrowImage?.image = UIImage(named: "side_arrow")
    }
    let headerClick = UIButton(type: .custom)
    headerClick.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.headerAction), for: .touchUpInside)
    headerClick.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: menuTableView.frame.size.width, height: 40)
    headerClick.tag = section
    headerClick.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    headerView.addSubview(headerImage!)
    headerView.addSubview(headerLbl!)
    headerView.addSubview(arrowImage!)
    headerView.addSubview(headerClick)
    return headerView
  }
  func headerAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if selectedIndex == sender.tag {
      selectedIndex = -1
    }
    else {
      selectedIndex = Int(sender.tag)
    }
     menuTableView.reloadData()
  }
}
```

But the error which is getting from this code is as shown in the screenshot below:
[image]

Why i am getting the error like this. Any ideas on it?

Comment: your headerImage is nil

Comment: How to correct this? I have already defined the header image as var headerImage: UIImageView?

Comment: You need to review how to unwrap optionals... Every time you use `!` - as in `headerView.addSubview(headerImage!)` - you are opening yourself up to a crash.

Comment: you can check if headerImage != nil before add as subView

Comment: Please post the answer to this. it will be helpful for me

Comment: Update your question with details about how you assign a value to `headerImage`.

Comment: @ChelseaShawra You need to do more than just declare `headerImage`. You need to assign it a value before you try to add it to the header.

Comment: @rmaddy what value should i assign?

Comment: My guess is it is supposed to be a `UIImageView`, correct? Is it an outlet? Did you connect the image view in your storyboard to the outlet? Or do you need to create the image view in code? You have not shown enough information in your question to know for sure.

Comment: Try defining headerImage as : var headerImage = UIImageView()

Comment: @rmaddy i am defining by code no outlet

Comment: So then you need to write code that create the image view and assigns it to the `headerImage` property before you attempt to add `headerImage` to anything or set its frame.

Comment: @rmaddy i have set the header image in viewforHeader

Comment: No, you have not. You need a line such as `headerImage = UIImageView(frame: someFrame)` followed by setting its `image` property.

Comment: @rmaddy     self.headerImage?.frame = CGRect(x: (headerImage?.frame.size.width)! + 20, y: 20, width: 10, height: 10)
 PLEASE SEE THIS CODE

Comment: I have seen that code. That is why I've been telling you over and over that you need to first create the image view. That line only attempts to set the frame on the as-of-yet non-existent image view.

Comment: ok I had removed my answer @ChelseaShawra can you tell me if you solve your problem? I think you are missing the part where you load your image from somewhere and assing it to your headerImage